# Validate a form on Click event with validator jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, submit, validation

I am using jQuery validate for validate an input. 
My code:

```
 $('#button').click( function() {       
    $("#form").validate({              
        rules: {
            phone: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                rangelength: [7, 14]
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
 <input id="phone" name="phone" class="required" type="text" />
 <div class="button" id="send_b">Send</div>
 </form>
```

This code is not working. If I add this line of jQuery

```
$("#form").submit();
```

inside the click event it works. But I don't want to submit the form so I want just to make the validation on click.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Give more detail on "not working."  What isn't it doing that you expect it to?

Comment: IIRC `validate()` doesn't *do* the validation, it *sets up* the validation for the submit. Poke around the code to see if it can be short-circuited, or if there's a method you can call that actually does just the validation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add [`.form()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form) to manually trigger the validation immediately (the default behavior waits for a submit event):

```
$('#button').click( function() {       
  $("#form").validate({              
    rules: {
      phone: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        rangelength: [7, 14]
      }
    }
  }).form(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is binding a function to the `click` event of a button. What you're doing is saying "when this button is clicked, apply form validation to the form".

This is the incorrect way to use the validation plugin (I'm assuming you're using [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) validation plugin). Instead, you just execute the `validation()` method directly onto the `form` element; the plugin takes care of the `submit` event.

So, get rid of the `click` event binding.

Comment: I just came across an issue where I am validating a single input box and the value is a parameter to a link. But I think you are right it will validate onclick automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use form method `form()` method with your click event