# Disable tabs when the data not pass the validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate and [jquery tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) to create a multi-tabs form

Assume a simple form :

> tab 1 for enter address, tab 2 for enter name, tab 3 for submit

html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">address</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#submit">submit</a></li>
</ul>

 <form id="selectList" method="post" action="finish.php">
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">//input box address</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">//input box name</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">//submit button</div>
</div>
 </form>
```

js validate

```
  $("#selectList").validate( {
      rules: {
         "selectList[]": {
              required: true,
              minlength: 1
          }
       }
   })

});
```

The problems are:

1. if the submit button is in the tab 3, it can not  validate the input box in tab 1, 2

2.　Can i not allow the user to go to other tab , when the input box in that tab do not pass validation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you can, but you need to change the behavior on the jQuery validate plugin, since it will fire the validations only when the form is submitted

Comment: not exactly, i think we can fire it in any client side events.

Comment: I've tried to do it on several ways and haven't been able to, so if there's a way it will be really helpfull for everybody to know it :)

Comment: create a simple form with a textbox and a button. And in the onclick event just do what we are doing in the form submit. Refer SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445423/validate-a-form-on-click-event-with-validator-jquery